# Null Pointer Exception in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, nullpointerexception, awt

I keep getting this error for whenever I try to use any of the buttons I've written into the code below. The strange thing is I'm looking at a similar piece of code and it doesn't occur there but I can't tell the difference.

Here's the code:

**Main Window Class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FinalPaintWindow extends JFrame {
    public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
    public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 480;

    ***ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        FinalDrawSpace finalDrawSpace = new FinalDrawSpace();
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == clearBtn){
                finalDrawSpace.clear();
            } else if (e.getSource() == blackBtn) {
                finalDrawSpace.black();
            } else if (e.getSource() == rectangleBtn) {
                finalDrawSpace.rectangle();
            }
        }
    };***

    private DrawCanvas FinalDrawSpace;
    JButton clearBtn, blackBtn, rectangleBtn;


    public FinalPaintWindow() {
        FinalDrawSpace = new DrawCanvas();
        FinalDrawSpace.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
        getContentPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
            }
        });

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(FinalDrawSpace, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel controls = new JPanel();

        clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");
        clearBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
        blackBtn = new JButton("Black");
        blackBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
        rectangleBtn = new JButton("Rectangle");
        rectangleBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);

        controls.add(clearBtn);
        controls.add(blackBtn);
        controls.add(rectangleBtn);

        cp.add(controls, BorderLayout.EAST);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setTitle("Final Paint");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FinalPaintWindow();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Graphics class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FinalDrawSpace extends JComponent {

    public Image image;
    private Graphics2D graphics;
    private int newX;
    private int newY;
    private int oldX;
    private int oldY;

    public FinalDrawSpace() {
        setDoubleBuffered(false);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                newX = e.getX();
                newY = e.getY();

                if (graphics != null) {
                    graphics.drawLine(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            clear();
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    ***public void clear() {
        graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }

    public void rectangle() {
        graphics.drawRect(oldX, oldY, newX, newY);
    }

    public void black(){
        graphics.setPaint(Color.black);
    }***
}
```

The areas with the asterisks are the areas that are throwing out the NullPointerException and I just can't figure out a way around it. Anybody able to help?

Comment: You need to add the exception.

Comment: For better help sooner post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

```
***ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    FinalDrawSpace finalDrawSpace = new FinalDrawSpace();
```

The problem is that in your ActionListener you always create a new instance of the FinalDrawSpace class. Since you invoke the clear() method directly, the "graphics" variable is not initialized because the paintComponent() method is never invoked.

Get rid of:

```
//FinalDrawSpace finalDrawSpace = new FinalDrawSpace();
```

Now the ActionListener code will reference the "finalDrawSapce" variable of your FinalPaintWindow class.

Also:

```
private DrawCanvas FinalDrawSpace;
```

should be:

```
private drawCanvas finalDrawSpace;
```

Since variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.